# extract files from only directory of zip

Tags: c#, unzip

I'm using Ionic.Zip, how extract files from zip file where is directory.

```
foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
{
    if (entry.IsDirectory)
    {
        entry.Extract(extractPath);
        var s = entry.ExtractExistingFile;

     }
}
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/209731/Csharp-use-Zip-archives-without-external-libraries

Comment: Do you want to extract specific directory or all directories?

Comment: I want extract specific directory. Then entry.IsDirectory is true crop up exception "Value cannot be null." in entry.Extract(extractPath);